# Is "ill employee" offensive?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, connotations

In the following sentence I would like to mention employees who suffer from a disease.

> **Ill employees** are terminated in some developing countries, but I believe that under
> fair-trade rules, workers should be granted leave if they become sick.
> Otherwise, I call it slave labour.

But I guess ill employee can be somewhat rude or too informal. Could you please give me an alternative?

Comment: The *sound* of "ill employees" is a little awkward because of the vowel repetition, but I would not say it is offensive or informal. "Employees who are ill" sounds better.

Comment: Is it supposed to mean that the employment that will be terminated, or the employee? Is the competition that fierce?

Comment: @WeatherVane It was not correct I  changed it. Thanks

Comment: You haven't fixed what @WeatherVane commented on. Terminating an employee might mean having them killed. You mean that they might be fired, or dismissed, or that their employment (but not they themselves) might be terminated.

Comment: *The employment of workers who are unwell is terminated in some countries, but I believe...*

Comment: @a.toraby Weather Vane is being pedantic.  "Terminating an employee" is perfectly idiomatic for firing someone and nobody would assume you meant they were going to be killed

Comment: Question - do you mean employees who have a short-term illness, or a more long-lasting disease that requires ongoing accommodation?  Usually you'd only use "ill" for people who have something temporary.

Comment: @Kevin not at all: at least 90 politicians involved in one country's election have been terminated, and they weren't even ill.

Comment: Nevertheless, "terminate an employee" is idiomatic for the less extreme method of ending an employment relationship.

Comment: Similarly, "fire an employee" doesn't  involve matches.

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw 'Ill employees', I thought it would seem quite offensive because 'ill' in the opening clause could also imply that the employees were "unskillful". So to answer your question, yes — there is a better way of writing what you mean with your first sentence. My suggestion's here below.

> Sick employees are terminated in some developing countries, but I believe that under fair-trade rules, workers should be granted leave if they become sick.